# Dynamic memory allocation with aligned storage

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a bit confused about the alignement requirements when `std::aligned_storage` is used and dynamic allocation is needed. Example:

```
  using storage = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type;
  storage* pool;
  pool = ::new storage[num_obj];
```

Is it legal? The new operator doesn't return alignment memory, so is the result correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++11 standard requires that allocation functions such as `::operator new` return memory that is aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` [[basic.stc.dynamic/2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.stc.dynamic#allocation-2):

> The pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer of any complete object type with a fundamental alignment requirement […]

Thus, as long as the type of the object you're creating via your `new` expression is not an overaligned type (one that requires an alignment more strict than `alignof(std::max_align_t)`), everything's fine. For overaligned types, you would indeed have to allocate storage of sufficient size to manually align the pointer, e.g., using [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align), and then construct your object at a suitable address, e.g., via placement new…

Starting with C++17, `new` automatically takes care of this. To allocate storage that requires alignment more strict than `__STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT__` (the alignment that allocation functions are at least required to supply), a *new-expression* will call an allocation function that is explicitly given the alignment of the storage to be allocated as an argument [[expr.new]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#14) …